# File upload error in Laravel 5.3 (error Call to a member function move() on null )

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5.3

I am writing a code for document upload for my application. I am getting the following error if i try to execute it i.e(Call to a member function move() on null).
Anyone pls suggest me where i am going wrong.

Following is my **DocumentInsertController** File.

```
<?php

        namespace App\Http\Controllers;

        use Illuminate\Http\Request;

        class DocumentInsertController extends Controller
        {
              public function insertform(){
              return view('document');
           }

           public function insert(Request $request){
              $destinationPath = app_path()."/gstup";
              $DocumentName = $request->input('DocumentName');
              $photup=$request->file('DocumentImage')->move($destinationPath);
              $VendorId = $request->input('VendorId');
              //$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
              $now = new DateTime();
              DB::insert('insert into documentmaster (DocumentName, photup, VendorId, UploadedDateTime) values(?, ?, ?, ?)',[$DocumentName, $VendorId, $photup, $now]);

                   echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
                   echo '<a href = "/DOCUMENT">Click Here</a> to go back.';

           }
        }
```

Comment: check file() output

Comment: Can you please brief more, sorry i dint get you

Comment: As the error shows you call move on null object. So check if the $request->file('DocumentImage') is defined.